# Efficiently remove duplicated values within a column from a huge file (70GB)

Tags: dataframe, language-agnostic

Hello everyone I have a huge tabularfile (76GB) and I would like to remove some row of this file.

Here is the head :

```
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei A0A653DM45_Callosobruchus_maculatus_Insect  100.000 45  0   0   4   48  65  109 1.563E-24   98  110
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei Q1HR02_Aedes_aegypti_Insect 100.000 45  0   0   4   48  102 146 1.563E-24   98  147
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei Q7PRY1_Anopheles_gambiae_Insect 100.000 45  0   0   4   48  102 146 1.563E-24   98  147
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei P25867_Drosophila_melanogaster_Insect   100.000 45  0   0   4   48  102 146 1.563E-24   98  147
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei J3JXP2_Dendroctonus_ponderosae_Insect   100.000 45  0   0   4   48  102 146 1.563E-24   98  147
```

and I would like to use an efficient method (I cannot use pandas since the fact to load the file is very very long).
In order to keep only the 2 first duplicated row in the first column.

So for instance if I have a file such as :

Note: the table is `tabular separated`.

Example ;

```
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     A0A653DM45_Callosobruchus_maculatus_Insect      100.000 45      0       0       4       48      65      109     1.563E-24       98      110
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     Q1HR02_Aedes_aegypti_Insect     100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     Q7PRY1_Anopheles_gambiae_Insect 100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     P25867_Drosophila_melanogaster_Insect   100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     J3JXP2_Dendroctonus_ponderosae_Insect   100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     A0A0L7KYD3_Operophtera_brumata_Insect   100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009917.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     A0A653DM45_Callosobruchus_maculatus_Insect      100.000 45      0       0       4       48      65      109     1.563E-24       98      110
CM009917.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     Q1HR02_Aedes_aegypti_Insect     100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009917.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     Q7PRY1_Anopheles_gambiae_Insect 100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009917.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     P25867_Drosophila_melanogaster_Insect   100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009917.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     J3JXP2_Dendroctonus_ponderosae_Insect   100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
```

expected output :

```
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     A0A653DM45_Callosobruchus_maculatus_Insect      100.000 45      0       0       4       48      65      109     1.563E-24       98      110
CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     Q1HR02_Aedes_aegypti_Insect     100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
CM009917.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     A0A653DM45_Callosobruchus_maculatus_Insect      100.000 45      0       0       4       48      65      109     1.563E-24       98      110
CM009917.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei     Q1HR02_Aedes_aegypti_Insect     100.000 45      0       0       4       48      102     146     1.563E-24       98      147
```

Comment: can you confirm what you're calling the `first column`?  for example, the first row ... is the first column `CM009916.1_1` or is the first column `CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei`?

Comment: the first column is ```CM009916.1_1:1212271-1212415(+):Neodiprion_lecontei``` (it is a tab separated df)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

If your file is sorted as in the example, this script doesn't take any memory.

If the file is tab separated and first field doesn't have any spaces you don't need to specify the field separator

```
$ awk 'p!=$1{c=2; p=$1} c&&c--' file
```

after each key change capture the new key and print 2 lines.

Comment: Doesn't `-F:` incorrectly make the field separator `:`?

Comment: the sample input has the colon as the field delimiter, I guess OP used as a substitute.

Comment: The sample input has tabs as delimiters. And the question even says so. And a comment too.

Comment: Oops I missed it.  Anyway, second one is right.

Answer (score 3):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print if $seen{ $F[0] }++ < 2' in_file > out_file
```

Example:

```
echo 1 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 | xargs -n1 | perl -F'\t' -lane 'print if $seen{ $F[0] }++ < 2'
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
2
3
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/\t/'` : Split into `@F` on TAB, rather than on whitespace.

`$seen{ $F[0] }++` : increment by 1 the element of hash `%seen`, where the key is `$F[0]`, the value of the first column.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to only do the dropping of duplicate for the first duplicates. I added an exemple

Comment: @chippycentra It drops any number of dups above 2, please see the example in the updated answer.

Comment: But here it has to be in the first column of the file, can you try the code on the data I provided please ?

Comment: The input has about 0.5 billion lines based on what was posted. Depending on the rate of duplicates, this could easily use up 100 GB of RAM

Comment: @chippycentra The code works fine for the data you posted, as long as the input is separated by tabs. If you accidentally converted the tabs into spaces, fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I know the perl and awk versions work and are nice and compact. If you wanted a version in python, I might naively try:

```
import collections
keys = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open("file_in.txt") as file_in:
    with open("file_out.txt", "w") as file_out:
        for line in file_in:
            key = line.split("\t", 1)[0]
            keys[key] += 1
            if keys[key] < 3:
                file_out.write(line)
```